# What is the role of render( ) function inside React Context?

Tags: reactjs

I'm learning `React` and came across `Context API`, while looking at sample code I found it has got `render () function`

Per my understanding Context react class component is there to manage state, so it's not clear why do we need to use render( ) function ?

Answer (score 0):

Class components have `render` methods. Class components can access the Context API but the `render` method is completely decoupled from the Context API.